# Duplicating an Imagefield on save() - django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project in django, I need to duplicate a picture stored in one model and save it with a different name into another one, I've tried many of the responses I've found but nothing seems to work.

This last try doesn't give me an error but is not duplicating the image, nor storing a copy with the name. I'm running Pillow and Django 3.X

models.py:

```
class Visualization(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='visualization', null=True, 
    blank=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    visualization = models.ForeignKey(Visualization, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hashed = models.ImageField(upload_to='hashedimages', null=True, 
    blank=True)

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        self.hashed = self.visualization.image
        self.hashed.name = 'randomothername.jpg''
        self.hashed.save()
```

Comment: Why do you need to make a duplicate of the image? Can't you just get away with having a ForeignKey to the model that has the image data?

Comment: My original problem is that I need to store a version of the image that looks the same but when hashed provide a different hash than the original file. First step will be able to store an exact duplicate before messing around with changing the metadata... thus the reason why I'm asking what I'm asking :)

Comment: fair enough.  Did you intend to override the `save()` method of the Order model?  Because you define a `saFe()` method instead of a `saVe()` method.

Comment: typo, fixed!!. Yes my original intention is to overwrite the saVe() method to duplicate the base image from the Visualization model, alter the hash somehow and store it with a different name on the Order model.

Comment: In your code are you doing this sort of thing: `Order.objects.filter(…).update(…)` or are you doing `order = Order.objects.get(id=…) … order.save()`?

Comment: the 2nd one, I'm assigning the 1st image to an object of the 2nd image and trying to save the 2nd image/object

Comment: Using `order_obj.save()` should work.